# Convergence of iterative process

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, optimization

I need to prove the following

[image: I need to show this]

and I have the following

Mβ^=v

[image: Where I know this]

[image: and this]

lambda_min is the smallest eigenvalue of M
and I've found the eigenvalue of the $\beta^n$ which is equal to [image]

I tried to use the Cauchy-Shwartz inequality to get some equation in form 1+x <= e^x, but couldn't figure out the way.

Comment: Where is this problem coming from ? What is the definition of $\hat\beta$ ?

Comment: The problem is homework. and $M{\hat \beta} = v$